# SpringBoot authentication using Okta with dynamic credentials

Tags: spring-boot, oauth-2.0, configuration, okta

I need to implement a custom Okta authentication. In my case, the Okta credentials will be dynamic, within my application I will have a record of these credentials for each user, so i can't write this information ClientId, ClientSecret, Domain, fixedly in the properties file

I didn't find in the documentation how I could dynamically set this information with Spring Boot, I found that I must change the information in the ClientCredentialsResourceDetails object, but it doesn't contain all the necessary fields for Okta authentication.

I need to dynamically include this information outside of the properties file before calling Okta's login page:

```
security.oauth2.client.client-id=***
security.oauth2.client.client-secret=****
security.oauth2.client.access-token-uri=https://***.okta.com/oauth2/default/v1/token
security.oauth2.client.user-authorization-uri=https://****/oauth2/default/v1/authorize
security.oauth2.client.scope=openid_profile_email
security.oauth2.resource.user-info-uri=https://*****/oauth2/default/v1/userinfo
```

Could anyone help me?